# How do I set the icon for my application in visual studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, icons

How do I set the executable icon for my C++ application in visual studio 2008?

Comment: The link in the comment is now dead

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First go to Resource View (from menu: View --> Other Window --> Resource View). Then in Resource View navigate through resources, if any. If there is already a resource of Icon type, added by Visual Studio, then open and edit it. Otherwise right-click and select Add Resource, and then add a new icon.

Use the embedded image editor in order to edit the existing or new icon. Note that an icon can include several types (sizes), selected from Image menu.

Then compile your project and see the effect.

See: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/87614e26-075c-4d5d-a45a-f462c79ab0a0

Comment: Awesome!! I was able to do these steps with Visual Studio 2010 as well... :)

Answer (score 69):

This is how you do it in Visual Studio 2010.

Because it is finicky, this can be quite painful, actually, because you are trying to do something *so incredibly simple*, but it isn't straight forward and there are many gotchas that Visual Studio doesn't tell you about.  If at any point you feel angry or like you want to sink your teeth into a 2 by 4 and scream, by all means, please do so.

Gotchas:

- You need to [use an .ico file](http://www.convertico.com/images/1329756536.52/Cursor%20drag%20move.ico).  ***You cannot use a PNG image file for your executable's icon, it will not work.  You must use .ico.***  [There are web utilities](http://www.convertico.com/) that convert images to .ico files.
- The ico used for your exe will be the ico with the LOWEST RESOURCE ID. In order to change the .ico

1) Open **VIEW** > **RESOURCE VIEW** (in the middle of the **VIEW** menu), or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to get it to appear.

2) In Resource view, right click the project name and say **ADD** > **RESOURCE...**

3) Assuming you have already generated an .ico file yourself, choose **Icon** from the list of crap that appears, then click **IMPORT**.

4) At this dialog `*.ico` files aren't listed, and you **can't** use a regular PNG or JPG image as an icon, so change the file filter to **`*.ico`** using the dropdown.  Misleading UI, I know, I know.

5) If you compile your project now, it will **automatically** stick the .ico **with the lowest ID** (as listed in `resource.h`) as the icon of your .exe file.

6) If you load a bunch of ICO files into the project for whatever reason, be sure the .ico you want Visual Studio to use has **the lowest** id in `resource.h`.  You can edit this file manually with no problems

Eg.

```
//resource.h
#define IDI_ICON1                       102
#define IDI_ICON2                       103
```

IDI_ICON1 is used

```
//resource.h
#define IDI_ICON1                       106
#define IDI_ICON2                       103
```

Now IDI_ICON2 is used.

Comment: Is there no way to *choose* ico file to use(ex: using #ifdef) instead of changing resource ID of ico file to use to the lowest?

Comment: +1 just for the `be sure the .ico you want Visual Studio to use has the lowest id in resource.h` (the Windows shell - normally Explorer - will use the icon with lowest ID or name as the default icon.

Comment: In my VS2010 the Resource View is in the `View` menu, under `Other Windows`. And in the `Solution Explorer`, right-click `Resources` to also find an option to add an Icon file.

Answer (score 10):

The important thing is that the icon you want to be displayed as the application icon ( in the title bar and in the task bar ) must be the FIRST icon in the resource script file

The file is in the res folder and is named (applicationName).rc

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
(icon ID )          ICON                    "res\\filename.ico"
```

Comment: This is only a requirement for the shell icon of the program file, i.e. the one shown in Explorer. The actual window icon can be set programatically to any icon, although the default is the first one.

Comment: Using IDI_MAIN_ICON for the icon id seems to work. I've had problems if I just picked a random number. So like:
IDI_MAIN_ICON           ICON                    "icon.ico"

Answer (score 1):

You add the .ico in your resource as bobobobo said and then in your main dialog's constructor you modify:

`m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(ICON_ID_FROM_RESOURCE.H);`

Answer (score -1):

**If you're using .NET**, in the solutions explorer right click your program and select properties. Under the resource section select Icon and manifest, then browse to the location of your icon.

Comment: This refers .Net apps, not plain c++ apps.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if VB.net in VS 2008 is any different, but none of the above worked for me. Double-clicking *My Project* in Solution Explorer brings up the window seen below. Select *Application* on the left, then browse for your icon using the combobox. After you build, it should show up on your exe file.

[image]