# Problems with setting application icon

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, icons

(I'm using Visual Studio 2008, though I remember having similar problems with older versions as well.)

I've tried several different methods (many of them mentioned in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008)), but I am still having some strange issues:

1. When including an icon as a resource, it does show up as the executable file's icon immediately, but for the icon to show up on the taskbar, I have to restart the computer.  Until then, it continues to show up as whatever the previous icon was.  Cleaning the solution, restarting VS, doesn't have any effect.  Not a really big issue, as it won't affect a released exe, but it would be nice to know where it's keeping the old icon cached and how to get rid of it.
2. No matter what I do, the icon displayed when alt-tabbing is the default app icon (square and white and generic).  This includes embedding the icon in the executable, as well as setting `ICON_BIG` with `WM_SETICON`.

As for the second matter, my code looks something like:

```
   hIcon = (HICON)(
      LoadImage( NULL, szFilename, IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE ) );
   if( hIcon )
      SendMessage( hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon );
```

However, after sending `WM_SETICON`, `GetLastError()` returns 6, "The handle is invalid.".  `hWnd` is a valid window handle, and `hIcon` appears to be a valid icon handle.  I've tried searching for reasons why `WM_SETICON` could cause that error, and at the very least, to figure out WHICH handle it thinks is invalid, but no luck yet.  I've cleared the error code immediately before calling `SendMessage()`, so it has to be set somewhere in the processing of the message.

I tried an alternate method, loading the icon from the exe itself, where the ID of the resource is `101` (it's the first and only resource included):

```
   hIcon = (HICON)(
      LoadImage( GetModuleHandle( NULL ), MAKEINTRESOURCE( 101 ),
      IMAGE_ICON, 48, 48, 0 ) );
   if( hIcon )
      SendMessage( hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon );
```

... but the same thing happens; after calling `SendMessage()`, `GetLastError()` gives the same error status.

I've tried different dimensions (such as 48x48, all of which are present in the icon file), but to no different effect.  I know it's definitely finding and loading the images, because if I specify a size that doesn't exist or an invalid resource ID or the wrong filename (depending on how I am loading it), it fails out long before `SendMessage()`.

Strangely, if I specify `ICON_SMALL` instead of `ICON_BIG`, the call succeeds with no error status, but from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632643.aspx), I need to use `ICON_BIG` to set the icon used while alt-tabbing.  Also, if I use `ICON_BIG` but load the 16x16 icon, I get no error status, but nothing changes.

Any ideas about what could be causing `WM_SETICON` to fail?  Anything terribly wrong with any of the code I've posted (aside from formatting/style/casting issues, as it's simplified to just the basics)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've revisited this to see if I can close out my question.  I have been unable to get the app's icon to show up in the alt-tab list just through embedding it in the executable; it will show up in the taskbar, as the file's icon in Explorer, and elsewhere just fine.

I figured I'd try something simpler for setting the icon manually, and went with `LoadIcon()` instead, as the code below shows:

```
HICON hIcon = LoadIcon( GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1) );
if( hIcon )
{
   SendMessage( GetHandle(), WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon );
   DestroyIcon( hIcon );
}
// ... Same for ICON_SMALL
```

This seems to have done the trick.  I really don't know why, but so far it's the only change that had any effect.  It's really not an issue I should spend any more time on, so I'll just go with this.

Comment: I run into the same problem today. Unfortunately this does not work for me. I have to search the internet for other solutions.

Comment: The `LoadImage` method works fine for me to show the icon in `alt` + `Tab` menu I had the issue where I wasn't setting the `BIG_ICON`'s `LoadImage` to 32x32, once I did that it worked like a charm. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24029664/1828637

Answer (score 3):

OK, this worked a treat for me :

```
HICON hIconSmall =(HICON)LoadImage(handleToYourApplicationInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON,16, 16, 0);

HICON hIconLarge =(HICON)LoadImage(handleToYourApplicationInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON,256, 256, 0); // Big for task bar, small loaded otherwise.

SendMessage(yourWindowHandle, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIconSmall) ;

SendMessage(yourWindowHandle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIconLarge) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used a single .ico file with multiple resolutions 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 96x96 without problems, as application icon. Then windows will pick up the right size.

The windows shell have an [icon cache](http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/4942/iconcache.html), there is a [trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffdav/archive/2004/07/22/191636.aspx) to restart it without rebooting or logout from the current session, or killing explorer.exe from task manager.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to this same difficulty if you are going to change ICON_BIG you must first send WM_SETICON with ICON_SMALL and then proceed to ICON_BIG.

For example:

```
SetLastError(0);
SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)iconsmallHandle);
[do error handling]
SetLastError(0);
SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)iconbigHandle);
[do error handling]
```

You will need to use SetLastError after the first SendMessage to clear any returned error.

If you are just setting ICON_SMALL you can ignore ICON_BIG. For whatever reason in all of my tests you must set ICON_SMALL regardless if that icon needs to change or not, before attempting to change ICON_BIG, otherwise you will always get error code 0x6 (invalid handle).

Comment: thanks a lot for this tip! this fixed the error "The handle is invalid." for the big icons!

Answer (score 0):

If found the solution for me. I created an invisible CFrameWnd application window and then a few other main windows (which are dialog windows). The magic undocumented rule is: You have to change the big icon in the first created CFrameWnd. While each window keeps it's own ICON_BIG instance, it does not use them. So it seems not possible to show different taskbar icons for different windows inside one application.