# Using Resource Hacker for changing the icon after the build

Tags: delphi, icons, embedded-resource, explorer, post-build-event

This question is written in several places (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207965/is-there-a-command-line-utility-to-change-the-embedded-icon-of-a-win32-exe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886561/how-can-i-edit-an-exes-resources-file-description-icon-etc-using-a-command)).

In the second question there is a comment that says to use

```
ResHacker.exe -addoverwrite "Project.exe", "Project.exe", "ProgramIcon.ico", ICONGROUP, MAINICON, 0
```

I also tried using `-modify` instead of `-addoverwrite`

```
ResHacker.exe -modify "Project.exe", "Project.exe", "ProgramIcon.ico", ICONGROUP, MAINICON, 0
```

but the result is the same.

The icon is changed: if I right click on the exe file and check the properties I see that the icon has been changed, but in Windows Explorer I still see the old icon.

If I open it with Resource Hacker (so not using it as command line tool, but as normal GUI tool) I see the correct icon in the "Open file" dialog.

Can anybody suggest a solution? I am trying to use this in a Delphi post build event.

Comment: I suspect that you are seeing the Icon from explorer's cache. If you are doing this in a post-build event, why don't you link the right icon in to begin with?

Comment: With same dpr I need to create 2 files with 2 names and 2 icons. (of course I could do it with 2 dpr, but this means maintaining both, while this would be perfect solution). ANYWAY YOU ARE RIGHT IT WAS JUST EXPLORER'S CACHE. If yuo post the answer I will accept it. THanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect that you are seeing the icon from explorer's icon cache.

Comment: Downvote seems a bit odd considering that the OP has confirmed that this is the problem!!

Comment: Yeah, it should be explorer's *icon* cache, the other might be mixed with the browser cache. <g>

Comment: @Sertac explorer is not a browser, you are thinking of Internet Explorer! <g>

Comment: yes of course I mean "Windows Explorer". Yes that was the problem I am now able to acheive my goal.

Answer (score 12):

David's right, Explorer's icon cache needs updating.

Add the following command to your batch file after your `ResHacker` command:

```
ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
```

<sup>(`ie4unit` is a built-in command)</sup>

No need to restart `explorer`.

Comment: I believe you want `ie4uinit -show` in Windows 10, but `ClearIconCache` in earlier versions.  You can (probably?) just invoke both safely (depending upon your context?).