# How to change the icon of the shortcut of Inno Setup uninstaller without separate icon file?

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut-file, startmenu, windows-shortcut

Is it possible to change the icon of the uninstaller shortcut in the Start menu without storing a separate icon file (to the app folder)?

I see this: [Using Resource Hacker for changing the icon after the build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165594/using-resource-hacker-for-changing-the-icon-after-the-build), but I cannot implement it.

My code:

```
[Icons]
Name: {group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}; Filename: {uninstallexe}
```

Answer (score 1):

An icon of a Windows shell shortcut can be set by an external icon file (what you do not want) or by the file the shortcut points to. So you have to modify the icon of the uninstaller.

---

You have to modify the uninstaller icon on a compile time.

You cannot do this on install time, as the uninstaller includes its own checksum. If you modify the uninstaller, it with refuse to start, claiming it is corrupted. Unless you find out how to also fix the checksum stored in the uninstaller.

---

But Inno Setup does not really allow modifying the uninstaller icon on a compile time.

What you can do, is to abuse the [`SignTool`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool) "callback". The command set to `SignTool` processes even the uninstaller. And it can actually do anything with the uninstaller, not only "sign" it. But it has to "sign" it in any case (Inno Setup explicitly checks that the executable was signed after the "tool" finishes).

You can achieve that by setting `SignTool` to a batch file (or other script) that will run the actual `signtool.exe` in the end, but before that, it will modify the icon (e.g. using [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) command-line).

For an example of such batch file that both modify the uninstaller and signs it, see [Microsoft SmartScreen - suspended using Inno Setup installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29067877/850848#29072495)

So this is doable, only if you do code signing (what you should anyway). You need a code signing certificate for that.

[image]

---

*Disclaimer: Adding a shortcut to an uninstaller to Start menu is against Windows guidelines (and creating Start menu groups is against Windows guidelines for Windows 8 and above at least).*