# How do I set the icon for my program in Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, icons, visual-c++-2008-express

I want to set the embedded icon for my executable console program to a custom icon.

I know this is pretty much the same question as [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008), but I'm using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition, and the Resources View is not available (and the Project-context-menu->Add->Resource... is grayed out), so I'm at loss here. Will I have to upgrade to a pro edition for such a basic task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still add a resource in Express edition, but there is no resource editor GUI, you have to create the resource yourself using external tools.

The Win32 Platform SDK has a [resource compiler (rc.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381042%28VS.85%29.aspx) that will compile a [resource script](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Resource_Script_Reference) which is just a text file that you can write yourself.  There are also free resource editors out there if you'd rather not create the file by hand.

The process is:

1. Create the resource script
2. Compile it using rc.exe to create a .rc file
3. Add the .rc file to the Visual Studio C++ project
4. Recompile

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your project's folder you should already have e compiled resource file called
"app.rc"
if you open it with a text editor you should find the lines:

> // Icon placed first or with lowest ID value becomes application icon
>   1           ICON         "app.ico"

just replace "app.ico" with your icon's filename and hey presto the magic's done.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. in notepad paste

AAA ICON myicon.ico


2. then save as resource.rc

3. add the resource.rc file to your project.

it works on visual studio, code::blocks and dev-c++

NOTE:
1. myicon.ico is the name of your icon.
2. myicon.ico should be in the same directory as resource.rc
```

- Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/22523/