# how do you use your own ico files for win32 program

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the icon for my application in visual studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008)

I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 express edition, And I wonder how I can use my .ico file for the exe instead of the default washing machine looking one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: Justin points to a dupe, so this should be closed

Comment: didnt help me much since i cant find "Resource View", maybe its because i have Express edition

Comment: Just right click on resource files in solution explorer > Add > Resource

Answer (score 1):

you can use .rc file within your project, but by using this your icon size would be limited to only 24x24 pixels, if you want to use higher resolution icon, such as 256x256 pixels like on Vista or Windows 7, currently you can not embed it using resource compiler, as an alternative you can use this utility http://www.rw-designer.com/res/ReplaceVistaIcon.exe and invoke that tools during your project compilation as custom build step, and this is easier than using .rc

Answer (score 0):

Create a resource .rc file and simply create your icon or import in to resource file, then compile your project.