# Set an exe icon for my program without icon file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resources, icons, executable

Normally, you can [set an exe icon for your program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393863/set-an-exe-icon-for-my-program). But how about set an exe icon for your program without icon file (at least for win 32 project).

In run time, I can set the icon with

```
SHSTOCKICONINFO appIconInfo;
appIconInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHSTOCKICONINFO);
HRESULT hr = SHGetStockIconInfo(SIID_DESKTOPPC, SHGSI_ICON, &appIconInfo);
```

But that can't set the icon of my *exe file*. I don't know if it's possible that I can do one of the following things:

- Set up project so that Visual studio can build the exe file with the icon from Window's system, like the stock icon SIID_DESKTOPPC.
- Create a text file code, so that the compiler read this code and generate the icon - I don't need any fancy thing - just a plain pink icon is good enough.

The reason I want to do this weird thing (yes, I know it's weird): Firstly, I want this whole funny project is just text - just code and code. Secondly, I can't create the icon file with Visual Studio, Paint or any other programs that come with default Windows. Thirdly, Just for fun.

This question difference with the question: [How do I set the icon for my application in visual studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008) : This set icon for exe file without the .ico file.

Comment: @François Andrieux: I just add the tag: Visual Studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the icon for my application in visual studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008)