# Is there any way I can give my app an icon?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, favicon

I am using Visual Studio and C++ to create a console app. I want the exe file to have a custom icon instead of the default windows icon.

[image: Icon]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170383/c-sharp-console-application-icon

Comment: "Is there any way I can give my app an icon?" - Yes. Many applications have managed this in the past. It most certainly is possible. What is your *specific* question related to achieving this? Where are you stuck? What have you tried? What does your code look like?

Comment: @Nandostyle That other question is about managed C# projects.

Comment: But the procedure in Visual Studio should be the same.

Comment: @Nandostyle But unfortunately, is not.

Comment: @Nandostyle No, that's a compiler option for [vbc.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/win32icon) (VB) and [csc.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/win32icon-compiler-option) (C#), so it is language specific and there is no such option for the C++ compiler.

Comment: I stand corrected, I though C++ had that compiler option.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/121245/how-to-change-icon-of-c-console-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# console application icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170383/c-sharp-console-application-icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could right click your project and select `add->resource->Icon->import`, then you could import your icon. Because the Windows shell - normally Explorer - will use the icon with lowest ID or name as the default icon. So, you could check if the ID of the icon is the lowest. If not, you could change it.

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393863/set-an-exe-icon-for-my-program) .

Answer (score 2):

You need to create `.rc` file (e.g. `application.rc`) and add it to the Visual Studio project:

```
IDI_APPLICATION    ICON    "application.ico"
```

with the relative path to the `.ico` file (just the file name if the icon file is in the same directory with `.rc` file, or use forward slash in path if it is in a subdirectory, e.g. `"resources/application.ico"`).

Comment: I can confirm that this is working - and the `/win32icon` option does _not_ work in MSVC if anyone is trying that out.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `/win32icon` is for VB/C# projects.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, but the article linked to in the comments mentioned it, so I had to look it up to figure that out. Just thought it would save someone some time :-)