# How to assign an icon to an executable on windows (or visual studio)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, icons

I would like to use a custom icon (a .ico file) for an executable, on windows (XP).
The executable is a C++ program created thanks to visual studio (2008).

How can I change the icon from the executable, to the .ico file I want?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the duplicate. I'm sorry I did not find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has mentioned in the comment, it is a  [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008)

Here is a copy paste of the answer from Jason Stevenson:

> First go to Resource View (from menu: View --> Other Window --> Resource View). Then in Resource View navigate through resources, if any. If there is already a resource of Icon type, added by Visual Studio, then open and edit it. Otherwise right-click and select Add Resource, and then add a new icon.
>
> Use the embedded image editor in order to edit the existing or new icon. Note that an icon can include several types (sizes), selected from Image menu.
>
> Then compile your project and see the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program such as [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to edit resources (including icons) of Windows executables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a "resource.h" and a ".rc"-file ,you define a identifier in "resource.h" (lets call it IDI_MY_ICON) and then add a line in the icon-section of your rc-file like `IDI_MY_ICON ICON "myicon.ico"` as the first icon (thus this line must preceed any other ICON lines). Rebuild ,that's it.

Answer (score -2):

In C# projects you right clink on project that creates .exe file, select Properties and on the first screen you can set icon. Not sure if this works for C++ but the properties panel is the place that you should look in.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able find it at the 'Properties' of your project. (By rightclicking your project name). It's on the Application Tab, at least, in Visual Studio 2008 working in C# it is, and scrolling down there a bit.