# Change C++ application icon in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, icons

I've been searching for an answer for an hour with no luck. I'm using the Express edition of Visual Studio 2012 and I want to add an icon to my C++ application. How can I do this? Also how do I change the description of the application? Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: I can't find the 'Resource view' in VS2012

Comment: @Martin: Don't use the selected answer, use the one that says `The important thing is that the icon you want to be displayed as the application icon must be the FIRST icon in the resource script file`

Comment: Apparently the Resource View doesn't exist in VS2012 Express. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cfawwc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Here's a workaround for that: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/457396-resource-editior-workaround-for-visual-c-express/

Comment: And if I create a .rc file manually will it be linked automatically? Also can you give me an example of what do I write inside of a .rc file? Maybe a cheetsheet or something?