# Application Icon Visual Studio 2010 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to clear a confusion here.

I changed the application icon for the .exe file using [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008). When I locate the .exe file in explorer I do see the change in the icon.

**However, when I run it on debug mode from Visual Studio 2010, the changed icon does not show up - it shows the generic white box.**

So I was just wondering if this is **an expected behavior or not?** My application will still have the new icon when I generate the .exe file in release build right?

Comment: It is expected.  Google "reset shell icon cache".

Comment: wow Hans, thank you! I never knew about this either!! :-)

Comment: Thanks! Please answer instead of comment so that I can mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant said in the comment:

> It is expected. Google "reset shell icon cache"