# How to set a Qt program's icon under windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, icons

I have successfully changed the icon in my window's left up corner using the .rc file.
However, the icon in the windows' file system remain the same as before.
How could I change that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please not that only that top left corner of the window icon is controlled by Qt: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/appicon.html#notes

The executable icon isn't a GUI element so it really has nothing to do with Qt. It can be embedded in the executable by visual studio though: [How do I set the icon for my application in visual studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320677/2642059)

Answer (score 4):

**In Qt 4**, you need to create a .rc file like this:

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "myIcon.ico"
```

You should add this to your .pro file :

```
win32: RC_FILE += MyApp.rc
```

**In Qt 5** there is an automated process for setting an icon to the application executable file .

You can just add the following to the .pro file:

```
win32: RC_ICONS = myIcon.ico
```

Also store the .ico file in your application's source code directory.