# How do I set an icon for my c++ application? I'm using visual studio 2013 express

Tags: c++

How do I set an icon for my c++ application? I'm using visual studio 2013 express. all the questions like this that have been on the same topic were all visual studio 2008 and i don't know if there's any different with the way the icons work.

Comment: How you set an icon hasn't changed in quite a long time.  It's the lowest ID in your resource script.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I believe if you click on the title bar in the design tab, in the properties panel, you would be able to select one.