# Issues with the Program icon

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, ico

I'am trying to change my program Icon for 3 hours right now now I cant fix some issues. Look at the screens please.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9rCyQS4.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yCVRgca.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yKTjyqO.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Windows Explorer Bug... After the restart everything is fine!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review this answer: [How do I set the icon for my application in visual studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008)

This video aldo shows how to add/change an icon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGkRAprmBdY

You might need to clarify what you've tried so far, if that doesn't help.

Comment: I checked that video before, the tiny icon is wrong, if i scale it up the right one appears...

Comment: So the small version of the icon just isn't working, big ones do though (for example the one on the taskbar)?

Comment: correct, task bar, title bar everything is correct... But if you use detail view in the explorer it got the wrong icon.

Comment: You should mark your answer as correct so people know the question was answered.  Good to know it was just a windows explorer cache problem.